# Why doesn't this compile?

Tags: c++, g++

When I try to declare iss using the first form, g++ gives me "error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'iss >> s'". But don't the two different declarations do the same thing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    const char *buf = "hello world";
    std::string ss(buf);
    //std::istringstream iss(std::string(buf)); // this doesn't work
    std::istringstream iss(ss); // but this does
    std::string s;
    iss >> s;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is known as the "most vexing parse" of C++: what looks like an instance declaration to you actually looks like a function declaration to the compiler.

```
std::string name(); //function declaration
std::string name;  //object declaration with default constructor

std::stringstream ss(std::string(buf));  //function declaration
std::stringstream ss(std::string buf);  //another function declaration
std::stringstream ss(std::string);  //also a function declaration
std::stringstream ss(std::string());  //ditto, argument names are optional

std::stringstream ss((std::string(buf))); //object declaration
```

Note the extra brackets in the last example. These brackets wouldn't be legal in a function declaration.

The first example with the default constructor is well-known. What adds unclarity in the second case is that brackets around parameter names in C++ are legal but optional. For example, you can define a function like this:

```
void foo(int (bar))
{}
```

Basically you'll run into this every time when all arguments to a constructor are temporaries from constructor invocations that take 0 or 1 arguments, and the quick solution is to put extra brackets around one of the arguments.

Answer (score 8):

It's because `istringstream` takes a const reference to a string. So you can't just write this:

```
std::istringstream iss(std::string(buf));
```

Well, actually you can, but it means you are declaring a function `iss`, which takes a `std::string` and returns `std::istringstream`. Equivalently, you could write:

```
std::istringstream iss(std::string buf);
```

It's pretty sick C++ stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some confusion about the type returned by std::string(char*) because this:

```
  std::istringstream iss((std::string)std::string(buf));
```

works.

Comment: This is because without the cast it declares a function called `iss` which accepts a `std::string` and returns a `std::istringstream` (the brackets around the argument name are optional). Since a cast cannot appear in declaring function arguments, this must be clearly a *call* to something that accepts a `std::string` (`istringstream`'s constructor).

Answer (score -1):

The first argument to construct an *istream* from a string needs to be: *const string & str* which this does not create:

```
    std::string(buf)
```

While the following code illustrates the point, it leaks memory, *so don't actually use it.*

```
    std::istringstream iss(*new std::string(buf));
```

Answer (score -5):

Don't you need to use `namespace std;`?

Comment: No, he's prefixed everything that's in the std namespace.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry!! you don't need to vote me off the island if I was wrong I made a mistake, everyone does. Give a guy a break!!

Comment: It's not meant as a personal vendetta – it's just an indicator that your answer is wrong, which is part of what voting is for.